# how can I remove shortcuts from my task bar if the link is dead?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar

I tried the Chrome development version for a few days, didn't like it because my tabs became broken and wouldn't load properly. I changed back to the live version, but I forgot to uninstall the development version, which gave me 2 chrome icons on my task bar, but they would both load a broken version of Chrome. I then uninstalled Chrome through the control panel and reinstalled the live version, but I now have one of those broken links on my task bar (a blank page with a folded corner) that points to a version of Chrome that's no longer there. Is there a way to remove this icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding the method purely by accident.

If you leftclick an icon in your taskbar that refers to something that's no longer there, you get an error message and the question if you want to remove that icon. Accept and it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the icon and select "unpin this program from the taskbar". Thats it!

Comment: Yes. In case you have problem with it here is the long way - press Win+R, type `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`, hit enter, remove your shortcuts.

Comment: Excellence, that's the problem, I cannot right-click the icon, the quickmenu does not show.

Comment: @Jet I don't have any icons there that don't belong there. itjust has the 3 icons (outlook, explorer and the working chrome link), but not the missing link.

Comment: Then you're going to have to do it the way Jet outlined. I don't know if this will work for you but I just discovered that if you left click hold down the button and drag it up, it pulls up the menu as if you right clicked it.

edit:
[This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/problem-with-taskbar-and-start-menu-icons-broken/0cca5548-2df1-4e0a-a10b-b39687618862) might be helpful to you.